# Need help in creating a database schema

Tags: django, django-models, database-design

**Current Database Schema -** 
I have these 3 tables, `Curriculum`, `Assignment`, and `Student`. Every `Student` is assigned a `Curriculum` through a `ForeginKey` relationship between Student and Curriculum. Every
`Assignment` possesses the same relation with the `Curriculum` using a ForeginKey.

**Problem Statement** - 
There are around 100 `Assignments` for each `Curriculum`, the problem is, some students need to be exempt from some  assignments, so I want a way that I can exempt a Student from Assignments 1, 2, and 3 but have the rest of the students do the assignment 1, 2 and 3.

**My solution that failed** - 
What I tried was, creating a `ManyToManyField` in `Student` table in relation to `Assignment` table. However, having to add hundreds of assignments manually would be ridiculously time-consuming for each student.

```
class Curriculum(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=SUBJECT)
    grade_level = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CURRICULUMGRADE, null=False)
    tracking = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TRACKING, null=False)
    required = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    recorded_from = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=RECORDED, null=False)
    semesterend = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    loginurl = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    weight = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LEVEL, null=False)

class Student(models.Model):
    epicenter_id = models.CharField(
        null=False, blank=False, unique=True, max_length=10
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, max_length=120)
    phone_number = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
    additional_email = models.EmailField(max_length=120, null=True)
    additional_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GRADELEVEL, null=False)
    curriculum = models.ForeginKey('curriculum', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Assignment(models.Model):
    standard = models.ManyToManyField(
        Standard)
    curriculum = models.ForeignKey(
        Curriculum, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="curriculum_assignment"
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS, null=False)
    type_of = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TYPE, null=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the best solution I could think of was creating another table to store all the exempted assignments, called `ExemptAssignements`.

models.py

```
class ExemptAssignments(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeginKey('student', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    assignments = models.ManyToMany('assignment', null=True, blank=True)
```

Now anytime I want to exempt the students from any Assignments, I can manually select them through the admin panel, as well the Student who's being exempted.

Now to get a list of all the assignments excluding the ones I have exempted I can simply use.

```
student = Student.objects.first()
Assignment.objects.filter(curriculum=student.curriculum).exclude(id__in=[x.id for x i in ExemptAssignment.objects.filter(student=student).assignment.all()]
```

And the above query will only show the Assignments which haven't been exempted.